# Pandas if statement concatenate string error when comparing two pieces of data in separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two sets of data, one is a list of Machines at the end of a network of conveyor belts, the other is the layout of the conveyor belts themselves. There can be multiple belts that join onto the same conveyor belt. I.E. Belt 5 and Belt 3 can both dump on Belt 2. I am trying to work on calculating the total length of the path as well as a list of paths for each machine back to the head end. 
This code is only trying to figure out that length back from each machine. Ultimately each of the conveyors will be broken into a few parts and some material properties will be passed along over time

I get the error

```
if Belts['Successor'][y+1] is Belts['Predecessor'][y]:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Ideas/Things I have tried so far:

-Originally I was using == instead of is, figured that because these are string values i'm comparing it would be that problem
- Tried re-indexing to be 'Successor' as the index before the if statement. didn't work and seemed like sloppy programming altogether

I know there is something very basic that I am missing here.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
BeltLength =0
Belts = pd.read_csv('Belts.csv')
Miners = pd.read_csv('Miners.csv')
Belts.set_index(Belts['Name'], inplace=True)
#print (Belts.head())
MLen = len(Miners.index)
Miners['TotalLength'] = pd.Series(0, index=Miners.index)
for x in Miners.index:
    print(Miners['Name'][x])
    Belts.set_index(Belts['Name'], inplace=True)
    for y in list(Belts['Name'].unique()):
        print(Belts['Successor'][y])
        if Belts['Successor'][y+1] is Belts['Predecessor'][y]:
            BeltLength += Belts['Length'][y] # Length is an integer
            Miners['TotalLength'][x] = BeltLength
            print(BeltLength)
            BeltLength = 0
            if Belts['Successor'][y] is Miners['Name'][x]:
                break
    print()
```

Is there a better way to go about this? I'm not a computer science guy doing this, rather a geologist-in-training. It seems as though somehow this could fit in some kind of tree structure and be really easy to do.

Comment: I think `y` is a `str` so instead of `if Belts['Successor'][y+1] is Belts['Predecessor'][y]`, try `if Belts['Successor'][str(int(y)+1)] == Belts['Predecessor'][y]`

Comment: That just gives a syntax error. I tried using .loc

Comment: (and .loc didn't work) it seems like there's some kind of indexing error but I don't know how to get around it

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `y` is storing a string from `Belts['Name'].unique`. So, in the case of multiple records sharing the same name, there is no 1-1 relation between the index and the record.

Assuming each name is unique and the data is sorted, as `y` represents a string of name which is the index of Belts, you need to find the index location (as int) of the record

```
# ...
print(Miners['Name'][x])

#Find the first location where index == y
index_loc = np.where(Belts.index.values == y)[0][0]
if Belts.iloc[index_loc+1, Belts.columns == 'Successor'] is Belts.iloc[index_loc, Belts.columns == 'Predecessor']:

# do the rest
```

In pandas is better to stick to `.loc` and `.iloc` methods for updating/selecting info.